# How to restrict function signature to only accept specific pairs of type parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have two sum types (`F` and `G` here) whose members are in a 1 to 1 relationship (I.e., `strings` goes with `boolean` and `number` goes with `object`).

I want to define a function `F -> G -> something` whose signature only allows certain pairs of parameters.

I can do this quite easily with function overloading, like this:

```
type F = string | number
type G = boolean | object

function f(x: string, y: boolean): any
function f(x: number, y: object): any
function f(x: F, y: G): any {
    return;
}

f('a', true)     // OK
f(1, { x: 1 })   // OK
f('a', { x: 1 }) // NOT OK
```

But this approach quickly becomes unscalable as the type families grow bigger. Is there a different approach to this which would work nicely in a case where `F` and `G` have 15 / 20 members each?

Comment: Interface? Have you looked into that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constituents in a union are not positional, so you should never rely on the position of a specific type in a union.

If you use tuples to defined `F` and `G` we then we can do something using tuples in rest parameters to get the correct signature and use a mapped type to merge the two tuples into a union of tuples:

```
type F = [string, number]
type G = [boolean, object]
type Merge<F extends any[], G extends any[]> = {
  [P in keyof F]: Parameters<(x: F[P], y: G extends Record<P, any> ? G[P]: never) => void> // [F[P], G[P]] would work as well byt 
}[number]

type FG = Merge<F, G> // this is [string, boolean] | [number, object]
function f(...a: Merge<F, G>): any {
    return;
}

f('a', true)     // OK
f(1, { x: 1 })   // OK
f('a', { x: 1 }) // NOT OK
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UDaBnYAnAlgOwOYBopsBXAWwCMJ0BdAKFEigHEFlyB7dgGwgENtC7cgCsIAY2B0G0ALJVcEADxwIAD2ARsAExRR+IJNUIs1G7bv2GAfKwDetKMgAKUHFADWEEOwBmsagBcUE686LykEBroKIoAFKpBMEhORlAgQSbqmjpQAEri7Ohaik6E+jYA-MzJgUQQAG5UAJQINvXsmFo2APTdyEkpxjXUUADu7MRcWmOF7nq6oxBcXFDkIMBQtAC+SCQUVHT04NAwLIhy6ArKxla0PsTYEpjs2FA+sQB0X7xBF1cwNyaQX0UHsjkc6EixHQ2AA3NtaHdYgByXjIwgYYgQFrgqC9KAAeQA0kiAIyEWxQBJQUlQLY4vF9YlI1Ho0FUoK0+mMqAAOQJABVCUSgA)

To get back the original unions you could always use `F[number]` and `G[number]`