# Typescript - return generic interfaces types depending on parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a method that turns arrays into javascript objects of various types, the interfaces of these types are similar to these:

```
export interface IService1 {
    header: string;
    desc: string;
    serviceID: number;
    ...
}

export interface IService2 {
    footer: string;
    desc: string;
    serviceID: number;
    otherStuff: string;
    ...
}

export interface IService3 {
    container: string;
    desc: string;
    serviceID: number;
    otherStuff: string;
    ...
}
```

And my conversion method is something like:

```
function convArrayToObject(datatype: string, fields: string[]): any {
    //logic here
}
```

The `datatype` parameter is a string that corresponds perfectly to the name of the interface that the conversion function will return (`IService1`, `IService2`, `IService3` etc etc)
I set the return type of the function to "any" for convenience but I was wondering if there was a method to make the function return the specific type indicated by the parameter `datatype`.

I tried with some overload but there are too many services and I was hoping that the `Generics` would come to the rescue. My services are all just Interfaces so any call to get Instance or similar are just overwork

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076090/how-to-restrict-function-signature-to-only-accept-specific-pairs-of-type-paramet), you can re-adapt it to your use case

Comment: don't think so, i would like to avoid overload (or type-merge) cause i have a lot of service and the number may vary in time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
function convArrayToObject(datatype: 'type1', fields: string[]): IService1;
function convArrayToObject(datatype: 'type2', fields: string[]): IService2;
function convArrayToObject(datatype: 'type3', fields: string[]): IService3;
function convArrayToObject(datatype: string, fields: string[]): any {
    // logic here
}
```

Edit: another solution

```js
interface RecordService {
    type1: IService1;
    type2: IService2;
    type3: IService3;
}

function anotherOne<T extends keyof RecordService>(datatype: T, fields: string[]): RecordService[T] {
    // logic here
}

const service2 = anotherOne('type2');
```

Comment: I have a lot of service to convert so I don't like the "overload" solution, I will give a try to the edited solution, thanks